# Qt /cookie - How send post on website (phpbb3)

Tags: qt, networking, phpbb3

My english is low.

I have problem:
I can't send message on forum phpbb3.
I can login. I can't send message.
Login to forum is success. Sending a post is not doing.

My source code:

dialog.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkCookie>
#include <QNetworkCookieJar>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    QList <QNetworkCookie> cookie;
    QList <QByteArray> listt;
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
    QVariant var;
    QNetworkCookieJar *cookiejar;

public slots:
    void mySlot(QNetworkReply *);
};
#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    cookiejar = new QNetworkCookieJar(manager);
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(mySlot(QNetworkReply*)));

    //login on www
    QByteArray postData;
    QUrl paare;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1/ucp.php?mode=login"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Firefox/3.0.10");
    paare.addQueryItem("username", "Moderator");
    paare.addQueryItem("password", "moderator");
    paare.addQueryItem("login", "");
    postData = paare.encodedQuery();
    reply = manager->post(request, postData);
    //end of login on www - effect: OK

    //send post on www
    paare.clear();
    postData.clear();
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1/posting.php?mode=reply&f=2&t=1"));
    paare.addQueryItem("message", "my message ...");
    paare.addQueryItem("post", "");
    postData = paare.encodedQuery();
    manager->post(request, postData);
    //end of send post on www - effect: fail
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::mySlot(QNetworkReply *e)
{
    if( e->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError )
    {
        qDebug() << "OK!";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR! " << e->errorString();
    }
}
```

It will help anyone? Thanks

---

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    cookiejar = new QNetworkCookieJar(manager);
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(mySlot(QNetworkReply*)));

    //login on www
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1/ucp.php?mode=login"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Firefox/3.0.10");
    paare.addQueryItem("username", "Moderator");
    paare.addQueryItem("password", "moderator");
    paare.addQueryItem("login", "");
    postData = paare.encodedQuery();
    reply = manager->post(request, postData);
    //end of login on www - effect: OK
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::mySlot(QNetworkReply *e)
{
    if( e->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError )
    {
        qDebug() << "OK!";
        qDebug() << e->realAll();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR! " << e->errorString();
    }

    //send post on www
    paare.clear();
    postData.clear();
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1/posting.php?mode=reply&f=2&t=1"));
    paare.addQueryItem("message", "my message ...");
    paare.addQueryItem("post", "");
    postData = paare.encodedQuery();
    manager->post(request, postData);
    //end of send post on www - effect: fail
}
```

Still does not work :/
Message not send.

qDebug() << e->realAll();
... The submitted form was invalid. Try submitting again. ...
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting message immediate after sending login request, before you get finished() of  manager.
So, When you are sending message request your login session would not be started.
Put you message sending code in mySlot()